# Is is possible to use Admob Ads for apps that are distributed via email or other methods?

Tags: android, admob

I see that Admob ads have a dependency on playstore services library. I was wondering if this means that if I distribute my app via channels other than play store it will serve ads or not.

Comment: What other channels?

Comment: For example if I distribute APK via Email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can side load apps and they will still display ads.

And while Admob is now distributed as part of the Google Play Services library, if the Google Play app is not resident on the device then ads still appear.

Answer (score 1):

While testing my apps on some "non test" device, I saw that the ads show up correctly.

I didn't click on them for obvious reasons but I think it would be counter productive for Google to allow advertisement to work only if the app is downloaded from Google Play.

They should work just fine.